# Display correct cumulative_sum value using Mysql

Tags: mysql

I used the mysql query below.

```
Select MONTHNAME(t.date) as month, YEAR(t.date) as iyear, t.income, 
    t.subincome, t.ssubincome, sum(rupees) as amount, 
    COALESCE((SELECT 
            SUM(x.rupees) 
                FROM house_details x WHERE x.id < t.id), '-') AS progressive_total, 
            (SELECT SUM(x.rupees) 
                FROM house_details x WHERE x.id <= t.id 
                group by MONTH(t.date)) AS cumulative_sum 
FROM house_details t 
WHERE YEAR(t.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND t.subincome = "Garbage tax" 
GROUP BY MONTH(t.date) order by t.id
```

and got the value below:

```
month    iyear   income   subincome   amount   progressive_total   cumulative_sum
January  2017    Taxes    Garbage tax 385      -                   125
February 2017    Taxes    Garbage tax 890      125                 1015
March    2017    Taxes    Garbage tax 200      1015                1215
April    2017    Taxes    Garbage tax 250      1215                1465
May      2017    Taxes    Garbage tax 270      1465                1735
```

The cumulative_sum in first row shows wrongly as 125.It should show as 385.I want to display the correct cumulative_sum group by month.
SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7b979/1/0

Comment: Please provide proper sample data set not the result of your query like `date` ,`id` missing in your sample data set

Comment: Hi @MKhalidJunaid, i have updated my question added an image of my table.

Comment: Forgot to mention that it would be better if you can create a sample fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com and provide your table definition and sample data set. Not in form of images we can't use this type of data

Comment: Hi @MKhalidJunaid i have added a SQL Fiddle please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to update is remove comparisons on id because id is not sequential as date January record can come after march or nay month record so this may result as invalid calculations. Second thing for cumulative sum and progressive total you need to do this when your main query is executed with `GROUP BY` like

```
SELECT *,
COALESCE((SELECT SUM(x.rupees) FROM house_details x WHERE MONTH(x.date) < t1.month AND x.subincome = "Garbage tax" ), 0) AS progressive_total, 
(SELECT SUM(x.rupees) FROM house_details x WHERE MONTH(x.date) <= t1.month AND x.subincome = "Garbage tax" )  AS cumulative_sum 
FROM (
    SELECT MONTHNAME(t.date) AS `monthname`,
    MONTH(t.date) `month`,
     YEAR(t.date) AS iyear,
     t.income,
     t.subincome,
     t.ssubincome,
     SUM(rupees) AS amount
    FROM house_details t 
    WHERE YEAR(t.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND t.subincome = "Garbage tax" 
    GROUP BY MONTH(t.date) 
    ORDER BY t.date

 ) t1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7b979/10)

Comment: Hi M Khalid Junaid, Thanks for your reply, I saw your demo but the value in cumulative_sum column in second row is incorrect, cumulative_sum is not grouping by subincome. I tried to rectify.

Comment: @KannanK you mean `subincome = "Garbage tax"` for sub queries also ?

Comment: Yes, you can see the cumulative_sum which counts the rupees which subincome is Light tax.

Comment: Thanks Khalid Junaid its working perfect. Please update the answer in Stackoverflow.

Comment: @KannanK Answer was already updated with filter of subincome = "Garbage tax"

Comment: No, in the stackoverflow window you want to update, so i can accept the answer.

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid your query working perfectly. I need cumulative_sum and progressive_total to be  group by subincome. I tried using group by inside subquery but it throws error as Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Comment: @KannanK its better if you ask new question

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, i need this grouping should be included. Kindly support.

Comment: @KannanK I am again asking you to ask a new question for your grouping issue by this one liner description its hard for me to have better understanding of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid I have posted as new question please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47689090/use-group-by-inside-subquery